# Gradient background with a sticky footer

Tags: sticky-footer, css

I'm trying to add a gradient to the body background which starts from white and ends in grey at the bottom of the page. Since the page has a sticky footer, when the content is bigger than the browser window, the body doesn't stretch/expand with the content. So the gradient stops in the middle. Can someone please help?

**HTML :**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="content"> </div>
        <div class="footer"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body { 
    height:100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #d5d6db 100%);
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
}    
.footer {
    height: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> background-attachment:fixed;

Add this to your body CSS.

On a side note you may know this already but: `background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #d5d6db 100%);` won't work on IE. This property is only for Mozilla Based browsers.

Cross Browser CSS Gradient ...
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

Comment: Thanks bunches! background-attachment:fixed did the trick. 
About the gradient, I just wanted to make the code clear for this post. Thanks again :)

Comment: NICE one! `Fixed` my headache.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set htmland body CSS to auto and remove size from body background gradient - see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/

Comment: When the size is set to auto instead of 100%, the footer wouldn't stick to the bottom. As Leo Haris suggested below, " background-attachment:fixed" to the body fixed the problem. Thanks for your help :)